# Libre office Basic macro is ignoring the last folder that I have added to the folder path

Tags: libreoffice-basic

Sorry if my wording is a little weird, but I don't know how to summarise what's wrong.

I'm using a macro in LibreOffice Calc which takes the selected cell and opens a folder in explorer. I want the spreadsheet to also find what folder it is in so that it can be moved anywhere and still work. So far, I have got it to open a folder based on the cell that is selected, and I can get it to figure out what folder it is in.

I am trying to tack on and additional part of the folder path that will be dependent on the selected cell, and then have the program open that folder.

Here is my code:

```
If oConv.UserInterfaceRepresentation = "Sheet4.A1" then
OpenFolder = ThisFolder & "/NewFolder"
shell ("C:/Windows/explorer.exe",1,OpenFolder)
End If
```

'ThisFolder' is the folder that the spreadsheet is currently in, and 'OpenFolder' is the new folder path that is supposed to be opened depending on the selected cell. The problem is that LibreOffice just ignores the   '& "NewFolder"' and opens the path defined for 'ThisFolder'. What's even weirder is that If I watch the variable 'OpenFolder' and go step by step, it shows the full path for that variable including the 'NewFolder' before it does the shell command.

How can I get it to open the 'NewFolder'?

Comment: Does the folder *NewFolder* already exist? Perhaps it is not LibreOffice that is wrong, but explorer? If the folder doesn't already exist, explorer will start but open anything (most likely Documents), but won't create a *NewFolder*. Try adding `If Dir(OpenFolder,16) = "" Then MkDir(OpenFolder)` before calling `Shell()`

Comment: Ok, so I got it to work. It turns out that when it reads the folder structure, it reads it with a forward slash. The shell command will open the "Documents" by default, and since I had the file there anyway, I thought it was going there, but not where I had added.

I got it to work by changing the function that detects the folder that it's in, to store it with backslashes instead, and now it works. YAY!